# Trying to use an ngMaterial stand-alone component, but getting no ngMaterial module error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I try to use a standalone component (chips) without using the whole lib. Since it is dependent on two other components, I included them too

```
angular.module('material.components.chips', [
  'material.core',
  'material.components.autocomplete'
]);
```

But I am getting `Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngMaterial' is not available!`

This error goes away only once I include the whole lib, which I try to avoid. This is the HTML scripts:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="core.js"></script>
<script src="autocomplete.js"></script>
<script src="chips.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

And the app `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);`

Comment: Did you ensure that your `core.js` file contains the modules that `material.core` depends on? Looking at the source file on GitHub shows that the file doesn't contain all of these modules.

Comment: You have to load the whole angular-material.min.js